# I can't see tikz result

Tags: tikz-pgf

With the following code:

```
 \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{balance}
 \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts 
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage[OT4,T1]{fontenc}
 \interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
 \usepackage{dcolumn}
 \usepackage{graphics}

 \usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                         % when including figure files
 \usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
 \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom

 \usepackage{newtxtext}       % 
 \usepackage{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font

 \usepackage{kotex}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \captionsetup{compatibility=false}
 \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
 \usepackage{tikz,tikz-inet,pgf,pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,shapes,automata,backgrounds,petri,fit}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}




\title{aaa}
\author{xx}
\date{June 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                semithick]
 \tikzstyle{every state}=[text=black]

 \node[state] (A)                    {$A$};
 \node[state]         (B) [above left of=A] {$B$};
 \node[state]         (C) [above right of=A] {$C$};
 \node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$D$};
 \node[state]         (E) [below left of=A] {$E$};

 \path (A) edge     [bend left]        node {25} (B)
       (B) edge     [bend left]        node {30} (A)
       (C) edge      node[above] {14} (B)
       (C) edge              node {13} (A)
       (D) edge [bend left]  node {6} (A)
       (A) edge [bend left]  node {4} (D)
       (E) edge  node {5} (A)
       (D) edge              node[right] {2} (C)
       (E) edge [bend left]  node {3} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I should obtain:

[image]

while instead I obtained

[image]

Comment: Can you please join your 2 snippets so that your example is a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? And try to reduce your preamble just to the relevant part...

Comment: @Rmano. Done! Thank you

Comment: While you load graphics/graphicx three times, the latter ones are probably ignored.  Note that graphicx loads/uses graphics to do the heavy lifting.  Graphicx just processes keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is the `[dvips]` in `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`. If you remove it, and compiles with `pdflatex`, then it will work.

Ti*k*Z will not work with a `dvi->ps` compilation, I fear.

PD notice also the warning:

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended.
```

...it's better to do what it says; if you use the IEEE documentclass you have to accept their caption styles, there is no sense in changing them (you'll be forced to undo them in submission).

Comment: Thank you! It perfectly works!